# Temporarily storing tester data on an interactive wireframe?

Tags: data, wireframe, usability-testing

Really just putting this out there to see if anyone knows of a service/site that does this? Looking to do some testing on a setup form / process. I need to store the users data as they input it so it can be recalled on later pages. *EX. adding things to a tree structure / miller column* Since we'll be working with different users, data will differ and thus the need.

Currently using Axure and invision.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Don't know of any wireframing tool that allows this. Normally, I would code up a basic html prototype and store this info using browser's local data storage as a JSON string. Each page will pull this from the local dataset. This requires some coding knowledge to create though.

Answer (score 2):

That's what Axures Global Variables are for.

http://www.axure.com/learn/advanced/variables

Input Field -> OnTextChange -> Set Variable Value (you can even add a new variable there)

Hope this helps